# How to retrain the TF / Keras Deep Learning model with smaller and multiple datasets

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

Here is my sample Code for a Binary classification example.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

dfLarge = pd.read_csv('CSV_DATA_Large.csv')
XLarge = df[FEATURES_HEADER].values
yLarge = df[CLASS_LABEL].values
X_trainLarge, X_testLarge, y_trainLarge, y_testLarge = train_test_split(XLarge, yLarge, test_size=.33)

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(X_trainLarge)
scaled_X_trainLarge = scaler.transform(X_trainLarge)
scaled_X_testLarge = scaler.transform(X_testLarge)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=18,activation='relu',input_shape=[14,]))
model.add(Dense(units=14,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=1,activation='sigmoid'))
```

> #Compile model on the Large dataset

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

> #fit model on the Large dataset

```
model.fit(x=scaled_X_trainLarge, y=y_trainLarge, epochs=100, validation_data=(scaled_X_testLarge,y_testLarge),callbacks=[EARLY_STOP])
```

> #Saving Model, trained with large data.

```
model.save('model.h5')
joblib.dump(scaler,'scaler.pk1')
```

> ################ Load the Model ############

```
saved_model = load_model('model.h5')
saved_scaler = joblib.load('scaler.pk1')
```

> #New Data

```
dfSmall = pd.read_csv('CSV_DATA_Small.csv')
XSmall = df[FEATURES_HEADER].values
ySmall = df[CLASS_LABEL].values
X_trainSmall, X_testSmall, y_trainSmall, y_testSmall = train_test_split(XSmall, ySmall, test_size=.33)
```

**QUESTION**

My question is that how to do multiple retraining (with Similar and smaller datasets) of the existing trained model without loosing existing weights.

I have seen many examples, but those are using pre-trained images from TensorFlow Hub.

Comment: This is email phishing use case. Do you think imagedatagenerator for my use case?

Comment: Right my bad I didn't read your question properly